# NoClassDefFoundError among others...Android

Tags: android, noclassdeffounderror

I am working on an Android application (I will call this ProjectA) that is attempting to login to a server through a web service call. This web service call is in another package within my workspace (I will call this ProjectB). I include the jar of ProjectB in ProjectA, and run it. I get this error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.commons.configuration.PropertiesConfiguration
```

Then, I tried adding several uses-library tags in my manifest. I add this:

```
< uses-library android:name="org.apache.commons.configuration.PropertiesConfiguration" />
```

I get the following error:

```
Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY 
Please check logcat output for more details.
```

I tried Googling this error, but the only thing that ever seems to come up in the searches with this second error is about the Google API's (mostly referring to the Map). If someone could help out, that would be great. Please let me know if you need more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your app, or some code that it uses, uses the Apache Commons Configuration components. You will need to obtain the .jar file for this code (which may have been supplied with whatever library you're using that needs it) and add it to your `libs/` directory to have it built in to your app.